# In Nuxt, how to add a script to <body>?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt app, I'm trying to add GoogleTagManager noscript to `<body>`.
As far as I know, the only way to do so is to add a custom app.html, here is mine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
      {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=xxxx" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Now this works fine, however the innerHTML part, the `<iframe></iframe>` is escaped.

This is what I get when I inspect the element:

```
<body>
<noscript>
  "<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=xxxx" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>"
</noscript>
.
.
.
</body>
```

How do I get rid of these double quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify **any generated html code** in your Nuxt app. What you should do instead is create/use a plugin.

There is a GoogleTagManager wrapper plugin for Nuxt.js that you should use instead:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager

Follow the instruction and you will be ready to go.

Comment: I tried to use this plugin but it simply doesn't appear to be working properly.